# How to logout iOS OneDrive permission UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, onedrive

i have OneDrive issue.

i tested OneDrive Sample App in this site.
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-ios

step:

1. clicked 'Sign in' button. and Sign in.
2. showed Permission UI. and clicked 'Cancel' or 'No' button.
   [image]
3. then Permission UI is closed. and re click 'Sign in'.
4. then Permission UI showed again.

if i want to login other account, i must click 'Yes' button in Permission UI. and logout and re login.

how to logout when i click 'Cancel' or 'No' button in Permission UI.

this is code:

```
[ODClient authenticatedClientWithCompletion:^(ODClient *client, NSError *error){
    if (!error){
        self.client = client;
        [self loadChildren];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.actions;
        });
    }
    else{
        [self showErrorAlert:error];
    }
}];
```

when i clicked 'Cancel' or 'No' button in Permission UI, error is not nil. so client(ODClient) is nil.
then signout method can be called. (self.client is nil)

```
- (void)signOutAction{
    [self.client signOutWithCompletion:^(NSError *signOutError){
        self.items = nil;
        self.items = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        self.itemsLookup = nil;
        self.itemsLookup = [NSMutableArray array];
        self.client = nil;
        self.currentItem = nil;
        self.title = @"OneDrive";
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
            self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.signIn;
            // Reload from main thread
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        });
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found solution.

```
[ODClient clientWithCompletion:^(ODClient *client, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error == nil)
     {
         self.client = client;
     }
     else
     {
         NSHTTPCookieStorage* storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
         for(NSHTTPCookie* cookie in [storage cookies])
         {
             [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
         }
     }
 }];
```